# Zipkin failing to start

Tags: java, scala, trace, zipkin

I am trying to install Zipkin on CentOS.

When I try to run `bin/collector`, I get the following errors:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/vagrant/zipkin/project
[warn] Multiple resolvers having different access mechanism configured with same name 'local'. To avoid conflict, Remove duplicate project resolvers (`resolvers`) or rename publish
ing resolver (`publishTo`).
[info] Set current project to zipkin (in build file:/home/vagrant/zipkin/)
[info] Set current project to zipkin-collector-service (in build file:/home/vagrant/zipkin/)
[info] Writing build properties to: /home/vagrant/zipkin/zipkin-collector-service/target/resource_managed/main/com/twitter/zipkin/build.properties
[info] Packaging /home/vagrant/zipkin/zipkin-collector-service/target/zipkin-collector-service-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Running com.twitter.zipkin.collector.Main -f zipkin-collector-service/config/collector-dev.scala
[error] Sep 24, 2014 12:13:42 PM com.twitter.zipkin.collector.Main$ main
[error] INFO: Loading configuration
[error] INF [20140924-12:13:52.285] stats: Starting LatchedStatsListener
[error] 700 [20140924-12:13:52.336] net: HttpServer created http 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9900
[error] 700 [20140924-12:13:52.349] net: context created: /
[error] 700 [20140924-12:13:52.350] net: context created: /report/
[error] 700 [20140924-12:13:52.351] net: context created: /favicon.ico
[error] 700 [20140924-12:13:52.353] net: context created: /static
[error] 700 [20140924-12:13:52.355] net: context created: /pprof/heap
[error] 700 [20140924-12:13:52.356] net: context created: /pprof/profile
[error] 700 [20140924-12:13:52.358] net: context created: /pprof/contention
[error] 700 [20140924-12:13:52.359] net: context created: /tracing
[error] 700 [20140924-12:13:52.361] net: context created: /health
[error] 700 [20140924-12:13:52.361] net: context created: /quitquitquit
[error] 700 [20140924-12:13:52.362] net: context created: /abortabortabort
[error] 700 [20140924-12:13:52.368] net: context created: /graph/
[error] 700 [20140924-12:13:52.370] net: context created: /graph_data
[error] INF [20140924-12:13:52.372] admin: Starting TimeSeriesCollector
[error] INF [20140924-12:13:52.373] admin: Admin HTTP interface started on port 9900.
[error] INF [20140924-12:13:52.375] builder: Building 1 stores: List(<function0>)
[error] INF [20140924-12:13:52.406] collector: Starting WriteQueueWorker
[error] INF [20140924-12:13:52.407] collector: Starting WriteQueueWorker
[error] INF [20140924-12:13:52.407] collector: Starting WriteQueueWorker
[error] INF [20140924-12:13:52.408] collector: Starting WriteQueueWorker
[error] INF [20140924-12:13:52.410] collector: Starting WriteQueueWorker
[error] INF [20140924-12:13:52.415] collector: Starting WriteQueueWorker
[error] INF [20140924-12:13:52.416] collector: Starting WriteQueueWorker
[error] INF [20140924-12:13:52.417] collector: Starting WriteQueueWorker
[error] INF [20140924-12:13:52.417] collector: Starting WriteQueueWorker
[error] INF [20140924-12:13:52.418] collector: Starting WriteQueueWorker
[error] INF [20140924-12:13:52.428] builder: Starting collector service on addr /0.0.0.0:9410
[error] INF [20140924-12:13:52.724] twitter: Finagle version 6.16.0 (rev=cb019fbe670d16dc8076494e315b4a8a6aa53111) built at 20140515-141056
[error] DEB [20140924-12:13:53.005] nio: Using select timeout of 500
[error] DEB [20140924-12:13:53.012] nio: Epoll-bug workaround enabled = false
[error] DEB [20140924-12:13:53.873] twitter: LoadService: loaded instance of class com.twitter.finagle.stats.OstrichStatsReceiver for requested service com.twitter.finagle.stats.St
atsReceiver
[error] 700 [20140924-12:13:53.932] net: context created: /config/sampleRate
```

I have installed Java 7 and Scala.

Note: These errors are from a second run of bin/collector. The first run downloaded libraries, compiled the scala files and then displayed the erorrs, however they were the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get the same messages but still be able to collect messages and view them with the web service. I dont know why the [error] prefix is in front of it but if you read the chars behind you see INF/DEB and so on... It stays for INFO and DEBUG.

Greets